# Large values in the inverse of a Hessian

Tags: logistic, python, optimization, hessian

I'm implementing Newton's method for a simple logistic regression model but I keep getting very large values for the inverse of the Hessian matrix. I am using the standard formulas found in books... I'm pasting a working example:

```
import numpy as np
from math import log, exp

obs_x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9])
obs_y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])


def g(b):
    negative_loglik = 0.0
    for i in range(len(obs_x)):
        val = b[0] + b[1] * obs_x[i]
        negative_loglik += log(1 + exp(val)) - val * obs_y[i]
    return negative_loglik


def grad(b):
    gradient = np.array([0.0, 0.0])
    for i in range(len(obs_x)):
        val = b[0] + b[1] * obs_x[i]
        val = 1 / (1 + exp(-val)) - obs_y[i]
        gradient[0] += val
        gradient[1] += val * obs_x[i]
    return gradient


def hess(b):
    hessian = np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]])
    for i in range(len(obs_x)):
        val = b[0] + b[1] * obs_x[i]
        val = 1 / (1 + exp(-val))
        val = val * (1 - val)
        hessian[0, 0] += val
        hessian[0, 1] += val * obs_x[i]
        hessian[1, 0] += val * obs_x[i]
        hessian[1, 1] += val * obs_x[i] * obs_x[i]
    return hessian


init_b = np.array([-7, -7])
print("Negative log likelihood:", g(init_b))
print("Gradient:", grad(init_b))
print("Hessian:", hess(init_b))
print("Inverse of Hessian:", np.linalg.inv(hess(init_b)))
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to CV. What is your question?  ("Can someone help me" is far too vague and open-ended to be suitable here.)

Comment: Newton's algorithm tends towards infinity pretty quickly. I am wondering if I have an error or just a problem with Newton's algorithm on the data I have.

Comment: It sounds like you need to debug and test your code rather than that you have any statistical problem.